# Python Key Error:1

Tags: python

i get a Key Error with this code

```
items = {
         'coke': '1.50',
         'mars': '1.00',
         'fanta': '1.40',
         'wispa': '1.50',
         'galaxy': '2.00',
        }
def list_items():
    for x in range(0,len(items)):
        print("Item:", items[x])
```

Here is the error log

```
line 12, in list_items
    print("Item:", items[x])
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing lists with dicts.

The keys of your `items` dict are 'coke', 'mars', 'fanta', etc. and that is how you access it like `items['coke']`.

To iterate the items, something like this is more usual:

```
>>> def list_items():
...     for k,v in items.items():
...         print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
...         
>>> list_items()
coke: 1.50
mars: 1.00
galaxy: 2.00
wispa: 1.50
fanta: 1.40
```

Comment: Ok this worked thanks and thanks for the formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're confusing `lists` and `dictionaries`.

There are a few ways to do what you seem to want;

```
myDictionary = {
     'coke': '1.50',
     'mars': '1.00',
     'fanta': '1.40',
     'wispa': '1.50',
     'galaxy': '2.00',
    }
```

When you iterate through a dictionary, you get the `keys` of the dictionary;

```
for item in myDictionary:
  print item
```

This will print

```
coke
mars
fanta
wispa
galaxy
```

If you want the prices (i'm guessing that's what they are), then you want the `values` too. There are two ways of doing it;

```
for item in myDictionary:
  print item, myDictionary[item]
```

or (an in my opinion, this is a little cleaner):

```
for item, price in myDictionary.items():
  print item, price
```

(I changed your dictionary called `items` to `myDictionary`, to avoid any confusion it might have caused, since the class method you want to get out the `key` `value` pairs is called `.items()`)